# dgrid sorting based on "get" function

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I have grid with columns with `get` method (an optional function that, given a data item, will return the value to render in the cell). I want to use values of this function for sorting purpose. What is the right way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

No, It is not possible. The sorting is done on the data in Store/Collection. whereas, the get method is related to the particular column of the grid and is called while rendering. Sorting is done before the rendering of grid.

You probably would want to add a new property to the data/store with the values in the get function. apply sort on that property.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to override sorting for using get method?